# image to show up when I press the button in java swing (error in frame.add( ) )

Tags: java, image, swing

Hello first of all when I run the program a button appear , when I press the button the image will go from top to down.
I try the code when the image go from top to down , it work very well
BUT when I put all the codes together there is an error in (  frame.add(new AnimationPane()  ); )

**Question : How to add AnimationPane()  to the frame ???
because this is my problem.**

The idea that I want to make two scenes , the first one have a button to make go to the second scene which will have an image (it must be pushed from top until reach down ).

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package maincontentpaneswitching;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class MainContentPaneSwitching {
    
    private static class ChangeContentPaneListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // I want to put the image here
            JPanel newFrameContents = new JPanel(); //Uses FlowLayout by default.
            newFrameContents.add(new JLabel("You have successfully changed the content pane of the frame!", JLabel.CENTER));
            
            /*We assume that the source is a JButton and that the Window is of type JFrame, hence
            the following utility method call is possible without letting any errors appear:*/
            JFrame frame = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor((JButton) e.getSource());
            frame.setSize(600, 300);  

                
            
            
            frame.setContentPane(newFrameContents); //Change the content pane of the frame.
            frame.revalidate(); //Notify the frame that the component hierarchy has changed.
             frame.add(new AnimationPane()  );
            frame.pack(); //Resize the frame as necessary in order to fit as many contents as possible in the screen.
           
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); //Place the frame in the center of the screen. As you can tell, this needs its size to calculate the location, so we made sure in the previous line of code that it is set.
            frame.repaint(); //Repaint frame with all its contents.
        }
    }
     public class AnimationPane extends JPanel {
 
        private BufferedImage boat;
        private int yPos = 0;
        private int direction = 1;

        public AnimationPane() {
            try {
                 boat = ImageIO.read(new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/memI0.png"));
                Timer timer = new Timer(50, new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        yPos += direction;
                        if (yPos + boat.getHeight() > getHeight()) {
                            yPos = getHeight() - boat.getHeight();
                            direction *= +1;
                        } else if (yPos < 0) {
                            yPos = 0;
                            direction *= +1;
                        }
                        repaint();
                    }

                });
                timer.setRepeats(true);
                timer.setCoalesce(true);
                timer.start();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return boat == null ? super.getPreferredSize() : new Dimension(boat.getHeight()*2 , boat.getWidth() *2);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            int x = getWidth() - boat.getWidth();
            g.drawImage(boat, x,  yPos, this);

        }

    }
    
    private static class MainRunnable implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JButton changeContentPaneButton = new JButton("Click to go to the next image!");
            changeContentPaneButton.addActionListener(new ChangeContentPaneListener());
            
            JPanel frameContents = new JPanel(); //Uses FlowLayout by default.
            frameContents.add(changeContentPaneButton);
            
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("My application");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //Tells the frame that when the user closes it, it must terminate the application.
            frame.setContentPane(frameContents); //Add contents to the frame.
            frame.pack(); //Resize the frame as necessary in order to fit as many contents as possible in the screen.
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); //Place the frame in the center of the screen. As you can tell, this needs its size to calculate the location, so we made sure in the previous line of code that it is set.
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new MainRunnable()); //Swing code must always be used in the Event Dispatch Thread.
    }
}
```

Comment: I put a link to the image, now you can run it.

Comment: There is an error when I add animationPane to frame

Comment: I tried to fix your code, but I couldn't get the image animation to work properly.  You rely way too much on static fields and methods.  Your getPreferredSize is backward.  Should be width, height.  Create your complete GUI before you show anything.  Use a CardLayout to show the button JPanel, then the image JPanel.  Separate your concerns.  Your drawing JPanel should draw an image.  Period.  You modify the yPos in a controller class separate from the drawing class.  You read all your images before you start constructing the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

## Introduction

As I said in my comment, I couldn't get the image animation to work properly.  At least this code would give you a solid foundation to start with.

Here's the GUI I came up with.

[image: My application]

Here's the GUI after you left-click on the button.

[image: My application]

If you're going to add comments to your code, put the comments on separate lines from the code.  Not everyone has a large monitor and can read 200+ character lines of code.

## Explanation

Oracle has a rad tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swin](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html)g.  Skip the Netbeans section.

When I create a Swing GUI, I use the [model/view/controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) (MVC) pattern.  This pattern allows me to separate my concerns and focus on one part of the application at a time.

In Swing, the MVC pattern means:

- The view reads information from the model
- The view may not update the model
- The controller updates the model and repaints/revalidates the view.

There's usually not one controller to "rule them all".  Each listener controls its portion of the model and the view.

When I put together an application, I code one tiny tiny piece of it, then run tests.  I probably ran two to three dozen tests, and this was mostly coded by you.

### Model

I created a `BoatImage` class to read the boat image.  It's a separate class, so I can read the image before I start to construct the GUI.

### View

I created a `JFrame`.  I created a main `JPanel` with a `CardLayout`.

I use a `CardLayout` to layout the button `JPanel` and the image `JPanel`.  This way, the `JFrame` is not constantly changing size.

I create the `JFrame` and `JPanels` as separate methods/classes.  This makes it much easier for people, including yourself, to read and understand the view code.

### Controller

I coded the `ChangeContentPaneListener` to change from the button `JPanel` to the image `JPanel`.  This is where you would put your image animation code.

## Code

Here's the complete runnable code.  I made all the additional classes inner classes so I could post this code as one block.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class MainContentPaneSwitching implements Runnable {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Swing code must always be used in the Event Dispatch Thread.
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new MainContentPaneSwitching()); 
    }
    
    private AnimationPane animationPane;
    
    private BoatImage boatImage;
    
    private CardLayout cardLayout;
    
    private JPanel mainPanel;
    
    public MainContentPaneSwitching() {
        this.boatImage = new BoatImage();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("My application");
        // Tells the frame that when the user closes it, it
        // must terminate the application.
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.mainPanel = createMainPanel();
        frame.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        // Resize the frame as necessary in order to fit as many contents 
        // as possible in the screen.
        frame.pack(); 
        // Place the frame in the center of the screen. As you can tell, this
        // needs its size to calculate the location, so we made sure in the
        // previous line of code that it is set.
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        cardLayout = new CardLayout();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(cardLayout);
        
        panel.add(createButtonPanel(), "button");
        
        animationPane = new AnimationPane(boatImage);
        panel.add(animationPane, "image");
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    private JPanel createButtonPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        JButton changeContentPaneButton = new JButton(
                "Click to go to the next image!");
        changeContentPaneButton.addActionListener(
                new ChangeContentPaneListener(this, boatImage));
        panel.add(changeContentPaneButton);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    public JPanel getAnimationPane() {
        return animationPane;
    }
    
    public void repaint() {
        animationPane.repaint();
    }

    public class AnimationPane extends JPanel {
        
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        
        private BoatImage boat;

        public AnimationPane(BoatImage boat) {
            this.boat = boat;
            BufferedImage image = boat.getBoat();
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(image.getWidth(), 
                    image.getHeight()));
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            BufferedImage image = boat.getBoat();
            int x = getWidth() - image.getWidth();
            g.drawImage(image, x, boat.getyPos(), this);
        }

    }
    
    private class ChangeContentPaneListener implements ActionListener {
        
        private int direction, yPos;
        
        private final MainContentPaneSwitching view;
        
        private final BoatImage model;
         
        public ChangeContentPaneListener(MainContentPaneSwitching view, 
                BoatImage model) {
            this.view = view;
            this.model = model;
            this.direction = 1;
            this.yPos = 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            cardLayout.show(mainPanel, "image");
        }
    }
    
    public class BoatImage {
        
        private int yPos;
        
        private BufferedImage boat;
        
        public BoatImage() {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/memI0.png");
                boat = ImageIO.read(url); // boat.jpg
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                boat = null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                boat = null;
            }
            
            this.yPos = 0;
        }

        public BufferedImage getBoat() {
            return boat;
        }

        public void setyPos(int yPos) {
            this.yPos = yPos;
        }

        public int getyPos() {
            return yPos;
        }
        
    }
    
}
```