# How to manage an Homepage (CardLayout on a JFrame) and other JPanels with a Controller

Tags: java, swing

This is the controller

```
package Controller;

import Gui.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Controller {

    Homepage homepage;
    JPanel1 jpanel1Gui;
    JPanel2 jpanel2Gui;

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Controller controller  = new Controller();
    }
    public Controller(){

        homepage = new Homepage(this);
        jpanel1Gui = new JPanel1(this);
        jpanel2Gui = new JPanel2(this);
        homepage.setVisible(true);

    }

    //METHODS
    public JPanel jpanel1(){
        jpanel1Gui = new JPanel1(this);

        return jpanel1Gui;
    }

    public JPanel jpanel2(){
        jpanel2Gui = new JPanel2(this);

        return jpanel2Gui;
    }

    //GETTER SETTER
    public Homepage getHomepage() {
        return homepage;
    }

    public void setHomepage(Homepage homepage) {
        this.homepage = homepage;
    }

    public JPanel1 getJpanel1() {
        return jpanel1Gui;
    }

    public void setJpanel1(JPanel1 jpanel1Gui) {
        this.jpanel1Gui = jpanel1Gui;
    }

    public JPanel2 getJpanel2() {
        return jpanel2Gui;
    }

    public void setJpanel2(JPanel2 jpanel2Gui) {
        this.jpanel2Gui = jpanel2Gui;
    }
}
```

This is the JFrame with a CardLayout JPanel as a container

```
package Gui;
import Controller.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Homepage extends JFrame {

    Controller control;
    JPanel guiJPanel1;
    private JPanel cardHomepage;


    public Homepage(Controller controller){
        control = controller;
        setContentPane(cardHomepage);

        setSize(400,400);

        guiJPanel1 = control.jpanel1();
        cardHomepage.add(control.getGuiJPanel1());

    }

    //GETTER SETTER
    public JPanel getCardHomepage() {
        return cardHomepage;
    }

    public void setCardHomepage(JPanel cardHomepage) {
        this.cardHomepage = cardHomepage;
    }
}
```

and this 2 are the JPanel that should be swapped when button is pressed in the CardLayout as main Panel.

```
package Gui;

import javax.swing.*;
import Controller.*;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class JPanel1 extends JPanel{

    private JPanel jpanel1;
    private JButton button1;
    private JButton goNext;
    private JButton button3;
    private JButton button4;


    Controller control;
    JPanel jpanel2;

    public JPanel1(Controller controller){
        control = controller;
        jpanel2 = control.jpanel2();

        init();
    }

    public void init(){
        goNext.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                control.switchPanel(jpanel2);
            }
        });
    }


}

////// JPANEL 2 //////
package Gui;

import javax.swing.*;
import Controller.*;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class JPanel2 extends JPanel{

    private JPanel jpanel2;
    private JButton goBack;
    private JButton button2;
    private JButton button3;
    private JButton button4;
    private JButton button5;
    private JButton button6;

    Controller control;
    JPanel jpanel1;

    public JPanel2(Controller controller){
        control =  controller;
        jpanel1 = control.jpanel1();

        init();

        
    }

    public void init() {
        goBack.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                control.switchPanel(jpanel1);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

I'm working on a project relatively big, i use, on this project a JFrame for each GUI and works fine, but now i want to re adapt it using a single JFrame with a CardLayout Panel that manage every JPanel.

The problem is:
The panel appear blank or says

```
Cannot read field "guiJPanel1" because the return value of "Controller.Controller.getHomepage()" is null
```

I hope i explained well. Thanks in advance and happy holidays.

Comment: Generally, in Swing, there's not one controller to "rule them all".  Each `Action` or `Listener` is its own independent controller with equal access to the application model and application view.  Here's one of my more recent [Stack Overflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69673366/image-to-show-up-when-i-press-the-button-in-java-swing-error-in-frame-add/69674660#69674660) explaining the concept.

Comment: Yes i know, i don't want to control every single aspect of the program with the "controller". But i only want to manage the way i can access to different gui classes.
For example, the initial idea was to have an Homepage and then after each "Action " the Main JPanel should swap to another JPanel but inside the same JFrame. I used a CardLayout blank and then added the Homepage on it. But seems that something isn't working properly.